# Autoincrement field on duplicate username

Tags: mysql

On registration i am asking a username for a game. But like usual in games the username is already used. To prevent overload by trying multiple usernames i want to add a system like discord have.

Exusername ***#0001***

Exusername ***#0002***

To keep it simple i dont want to add more than 4 numbers after name.

How can i make a autoincrement field which is connected to the usename?
Only if a user name is already used it should increment by one, else it starts by 1 withouth making a first fetch (there will be millions of rows).
Or can you give me better advise to solve my issue ?

For example registration timeline:

```
Exuser1 -> 0001
Exuser2 -> 0001
Exuser3 -> 0001
Exuser2 -> 0002
Exuser2 -> 0003
```

Comment: @ErgestBasha   Both is fine, a new user could be registered with Exuser2#0002 or Exuser2#0004, doesnt matter. It will rarely happen because accounts dont get deleted when the app is removed.

Comment: *How can i make a autoincrement field which is connected to the usename?* The most simple solution uses MyISAM table with secondary autoincremented column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
    username VARCHAR(250),
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (username, id)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/NCnMAV6p

---

> i already have primary key, which is a unique identifier provided by google – user5441400

If so then (trigger + additional table) seems to be the only solution.

```sql
CREATE TABLE users_enumeration (
    username VARCHAR(250),
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (username, id)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_users_make_fullname
BEFORE INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE last_id INT;
  INSERT INTO users_enumeration (username) 
    VALUES (NEW.username);
  SET last_id := LAST_INSERT_ID();
  DELETE FROM users_enumeration
    WHERE username = NEW.username AND id < last_id;
  SET NEW.fullname = CONCAT_WS('#', NEW.username, LPAD(last_id, 4, 0));
END
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/R-YMICE4

Comment: I forgot to add that i already have primary key, which is a unique identifier provided by google and im not sure joining a second table only to display name might cause a little overhead aswell.

Comment: @user5441400 The answer updated.